# Host parameters not available in mux.Vars()

Tags: go, mux

I am using Gorilla mux routing with a wildcard subdomain. However, the subdomain value is not being populated in `mux.Vars()`. Here is my example program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    log.Println(vars)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello")
}

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.Host("{subdomain}.localhost.com").Path("/{id}").HandlerFunc(indexHandler)

    srv := &http.Server{
        Handler: router,
        Addr:    ":8080",
    }
    log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServe())
}
```

I am navigating to `http://sub.localhost.com:8080/123`, and I have my `/etc/hosts` file updated with this subdomain accordingly. Mux is correctly finding this route in displaying `hello` in the browser.

In this case, I am expecting `vars` to have two keys: `subdomain` and `id`, with values `sub` and `123` respectively. However, when I print the value of `vars`, here is the output:

```
map[id:123]
```

Why is `subdomain` missing? And how can I access that value from my handler?

Answer (score 0):

Your test URL format is incorrect. You are using

```
http://sub.localhost.com/123:8080
```

which yields a URL path of `/123:8080` - most likely an invalid ID.

You want instead:

```
http://sub.localhost.com:8080/123
```

which yields a URL path of `/123` that matches your router.

Comment: Ah, I had the wrong code in my example! I have fixed the code. The confusing bit is why the value of `{subdomain}` is not present in `mux.Vars()` - any insight on that?

Comment: I compiled your code on my MacOS system and got the expected results. `curl http://sub.localhost.com:8080/123` produced `hello`. Server-side log: `2020/07/13 23:43:11 map[id:123 subdomain:sub]`

Comment: @poundifdef ensure you have the latest version: `go get -u github.com/gorilla/mux`